# When adding a node to linked list, it overwrites all the previous one

Tags: c

After adding several nodes with different strings, print() only outputs the last inserted node's values. If I've inserted 10 different nodes with the last node containing "FirstString" and "SecondString", It will print that out 10 times. I'm assuming that there is something wrong with my insertLast that it overrides all the previous nodes by the new one.

```
LinkedList* newLinkedList()                                                     
{                                                                               
   LinkedList* list;                                                            
   list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));                              
   (*list).head = NULL;                                                         
   (*list).tail = NULL;                                                         
   return list;                                                                 
} 



void insertLast( struct LinkedList* list, char* inCommand, char* inValue )
{                                                                               
   LinkedListNode* newNode;                                                     

   printf( "Command:%s Value:%s\n", inCommand, inValue );                       
   newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));                   
   (*newNode).command = malloc( 10 * sizeof( char ) );                          
   (*newNode).value = malloc( 3 * sizeof( char ) );                             
   (*newNode).command = inCommand;                                              
   (*newNode).value = inValue;                                                  
   newNode->next = NULL;                                                        

   if( list->head == NULL )                                                     
   {                                                                            
      list->head = newNode;                                                     
      list->tail = newNode;                                                     

   }                                                                            
   else                                                                         
   {                                                                            
      list->tail->next = newNode;                                               
      list->tail = newNode;                                                     
   }                                                                            
   printf( "Start:%s %s \n", list->head->command, list->head->value );          
   printf( "End:%s %s \n", list->tail->command, list->tail->value );            

}
void print( struct LinkedList* list )                                           
{                                                                               
   LinkedListNode* current = list->head;                                        
   while( current!= NULL )                                                      
   {                                                                            
      printf( "\n%s : %s \n", current->command, current->value );
      current = current->next;
   }                                                                            
}
```

Comment: `(*newNode).command = inCommand;` doesn't make a copy of the string. All it does is change the pointer. Which means that the memory from `malloc` is leaked.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but instead of writing `(*newNode).command ` you should write `newNode->command` etc. It's equivalent, but nobody uses the first notation.

Answer (score 1):

Changed my insertLast() to use strcpy, it now seems to work fine. :) Thanks for the responses.

```
void insertLast( struct LinkedList* list, char* inCommand, char* inValue )
{                                                                               
   LinkedListNode* newNode;                                                     

   newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));                   
   newNode->command = malloc( 10 * sizeof( char ) );                            
   newNode->value = malloc( 3 * sizeof( char ) );                               
   strcpy( newNode->command, inCommand );                                       
   strcpy( newNode->value, inValue );                                           
   newNode->next = NULL;                                                        

   if( list->head == NULL )                                                     
   {                                                                            
      list->head = newNode;                                                     
      list->tail = newNode;                                                     

   }                                                                            
   else                                                                         
   {                                                                            
      list->tail->next = newNode;                                               
      list->tail = newNode;                                                     
   }                                                                            
}
```

Comment: use `strlen`+1 to calculate the length of `inCommand` and `inValue` in `malloc` instead of magic numbers.

Comment: And don't cast the return of `malloc`.

Comment: You can also checkout strdup. It can be used instead of malloc and copy. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `(*newNode).command = inCommand`, try

```
memcpy(newNode->command, inCommand, strlen(inCommand));
newNode->command[strlen(inCommand)] = 0;
```

This will copy the value, instead of pointing to the same value as `inCommand`.

So if you are using a same variable in the main code to assign a value to `inCommand`, with the way you are doing now, all nodes will point to the same value. Everytime you change the value of that variable, they'll all change!

Comment: Why use `memcpy` and not `strcpy`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky `strcpy` works too... I think my answer is biaised by the fact that I am used to working with binary data that often contains `0` value inside. But I don't want it to be considered as end of string.